# Perl regex replace

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to take a file, and copy it to an output file and then find all the `<k>` and make them into `<p>` instead. I want to use regex.

```
  while (<INPUTFILE>)
  {
         if($_ != "<p>")
         {
                print OUTPUTFILE "$_\n";  
          }

          else
          {
              print OUTPUTFILE "<k>";  
            }

  }
```

I was trying something like this but I guess the $_ variable takes each line at a time.
So It would prob be better to use write the entire file then try the regex search and replace? for that I have tried:

```
  $_ =~ s/<k>/<p>/g;
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the file content? Is it simply either `<p>` or `<k>` on lines or is there more content?

Comment: Your code seems to be looking for `<p>` in the input and printing `<k>` when it finds it. Your description has the inverse logic. Which is right?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have found a major error.

Comment: Unless you use `chop` or `chomp`, `$_` already ends with a newline. So you shouldn't add one when you `print OUTPUTFILE "$_";`.

Comment: To expand on @Barmar's comment:  since you aren't `chomp`ing the input, $_ contains a newline, your if($_ != "<p>") will always be !=, since your test literal has no newline - unless your input file ends with a line that isn't newline-terminated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A line at a time is not a problem.

```
while (<>)
   s/<k>/<p>/g;
   print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ikegami suggests, one line at a time is no problem. Alternatively, you could do this in a single search and replace:

```
{
   local $/ = undef;
   my $data = <INPUTFILE>;
   $data =~ s/<k>/<p>/g;
}
```

This would do the search and replace in a single operation and might be faster and/or more efficient for larger files.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to treat the whole file in one time :

```
BEGIN { $/ = undef; $\ = undef; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/<k>/<p>/g;
    print $_;
}
```

From :

```
perl -0777 -MO=Deparse -pe 's/<k>/<p>/g; print;'
```

Comment: I think you were trying to slurp the file, but 1) you weren't (so I fixed it), and 2) it's useless. // And now you added `/m` (which changes what unused `^` and `$` match) and `/s` (which changes what unused `.` matches). Also useless.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line

```
perl -pe 's/<k>/<p>/g' <infile >outfile
```

Simples.... :-)

Look up 'change record separator' if you are concerned about newline effects